# How to overcome Error: Constant expression expected when trying to pass data to a custom class in Flutter / dart

Tags: flutter, dart

I have this data model

```
class ThreadVars{

  late int threadid;
  late String threadtitle;

  ThreadVars({
    required this.threadid,
    required this.threadtitle,
  });

}
```

And I'm trying to transport data into another class as follows:

```
class ThreadData with ChangeNotifier
{
  final String url;
  final ThreadVars tVars;

  // Defaults to some default data if not passed as parameter
  ThreadData({
    this.url = '',
    this.tVars = ThreadVars(threadtitle: 'Temp', threadid: 0)
  });

.... ETC

}
```

I'm transporting the data into this class from a list view onTap as follows:

```
  onTap: () {


    Navigator.push(
    context,
    new MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => ChangeNotifierProvider(
                create: (context) => ThreadData(
                    url:'',
                    tVars: ThreadVars(
                        threadid: map['threadid'],
                        threadtitle: map['title'])
                      ),
                builder: (context, child)
                  {
                  return OpenThread();
                               
                  },
                ),
            )
      );
```

### **The Problem**

This line of code

```
  ThreadData({
    this.url = '',
    this.tVars = ThreadVars(threadtitle: 'asd', threadid: 0)
  });
```

Specifically the **tVars** gives me a few errors:

- The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.
- Error: Constant expression expected.
  Try inserting 'const'.
- Error: Cannot invoke a non-'const' constructor where a const expression is expected.
  Try using a constructor or factory that is 'const'.

I pretty want it to just be blank as there will always be good data being passed to it, but any variation I try always fails as follows as it always wants a value of type ThreadVars

```
this.tVars = {}
this.tVars = []
this.tVars = ''
this.tVars = 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained by the error message, default arguments must be constants.  In your case, you can just give your `ThreadVars` class a `const` constructor if you don't need to mutate its members:

```dart
class ThreadVars{
  final int threadid;
  final String threadtitle;

  const ThreadVars({
    required this.threadid,
    required this.threadtitle,
  });
}
```

and then construct a `const ThreadVars` as the default argument:

```dart
  ThreadData({
    this.url = '',
    this.tVars = const ThreadVars(threadtitle: 'asd', threadid: 0)
  });
```

Also note that there's no reason to make `threadid` and `threadtitle` `late`; the constructor requires them and will initialize them immediately.

In general, there can be cases where you can't make a class have a `const` constructor.  In such cases, you instead would want to [use a sentinel value (e.g. `null`) and to check for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961300/).

Comment: Thank you!  This worked with one caveat (for anyone else having this problem).  I had to make threadid and threadtitle as 'final' in the top declaration in class ThreadVars

Comment: Oops, fixed.  Yes, a `const` constructor would require `final` members.

Answer (score -1):

Because values of `ThreadVars` instance can change you can assign it to final variable.
Try removing final keyword from the `tVars`

Comment: Seems to show the same set of errors if I remove final