# List null safety Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How do you initialize a `List<Object>` in a constructor when using null safety in flutter without the `required` keyword ?

I have the following code :

```
List<String> test = [];
MyConstructor({this.test});
```

There is a compile error telling me to add the `required` keyword, but if i do :

```
List<String> test = [];
MyConstructor({this.test=[]});
```

This gives me an error that `the default value of a named param must be constant`.
Of course i can put the `required` keyword and everything is fine, but in all of my constructors i need to add an empty `List` it's quite boring because only in 10% of the time i need to pass a non empty `List`.

Can you simply confirm that the `required` keyword is the only option ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Use a `const` initializer:

  ```dart
  List<String> test;
  MyConstructor({this.test = const []});
  ```

  However, that will be awkward if you need to mutate your `List` later (and make it impossible if your `List` member is also `final`).
- Mark the parameter as `required`.
- Make the *parameter* (but not the member) nullable:

  ```dart
  List<String> test;
  MyConstructor({List<String>? test})
    : test = test ?? [];
  ```

  Also see: [The default value of an optional parameter must be constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961300/)
- Make both the member and the parameter nullable.

Comment: Thank you very much, can i use your last syntax to do so with multiple ```List``` to initialize ? 
I am aware that this may be beyond this question scope, but can i achieve something similar with ```VoidCallback``` (functions) objects ? Or they should always be required ?

Comment: Thank you @TirthPatel ! 
I have accepted this answer because it provides this new approach that i had no idea about and i didn't want to use positional parameters

Comment: That's alright. I'm here to help, not to collect points :D

Answer (score 1):

You could use positional parameter instead.

```dart
class MyConstructor {
  List<String> test = [];
  MyConstructor(this.test);
}
```

You could use const literal as a default value with optional parameter.

```dart
class MyConstructor {
  List<String> test = [];
  MyConstructor({this.test = const []});
}
```

Comment: BTW, positional vs. named is orthogonal to required vs. optional.  An *optional* positional parameter would have the same problem.

Comment: Didn't get you, could you come again?

Comment: Your example doesn't avoid the problem because it uses a parameter that is *positional*; it avoids the problem because it uses a *required* parameter (that happens to be positional).  If the parameter were an optional, positional parameter (i.e., `MyConstructor([this.test = []])`), it would have the same problem of needing a non-null, `const` default value.

Answer (score 0):

Just add const before empty list, like this:

```
  List<String> test = [];
  MyConstructor({this.test = const []});
```