# How to define value in the constructor to pass to the super constructor in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some code like:

```
class P extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<int> l;
  final int x;

  const P({
    required this.l,
    required this.x,
    Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

}

class A extends P {
  A({required int x, Key? key}) : super(l: [], x: x, key: key);
}
```

and what I would like to do is changing `A` class constructor in something like:

```
A({required int x, Key? key}) {
  final int a = 3;
  final int b = 5;
  final int c = -1;
}: super(l: [a, b, c], x: x, key: key);
```

is there a way to achieve something like that with Dart?

*UPDATE*

The version suggested by Yeasin works for the simple case from my example, but it fails if the case is more complicated like:

```
class A extends P {
  A({
    required int x,
    Key? key,
    ChangeNotifierProvider<UIComponentState> a = ChangeNotifierProvider<UIComponentState>((ref) => UIComponentState()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<UIComponentState> b = ChangeNotifierProvider<UIComponentState>((ref) => UIComponentState()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider<UIComponentState> c = ChangeNotifierProvider<UIComponentState>((ref) => UIComponentState()),
  }) : super(l: [a, b, c], l2: [a, b, c], x: x, key: key);
}
```

as I get the error:

> The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.

Comment: Unless you plan on using `a`, `b`, and `c` later, adding variables for them is not very useful, especially when they're constants.  You therefore could just use `super(l: [3, 5, -1], x: x, key: key)` directly.  Or perhaps you want variables because you actually want them to store intermediate computations?

Comment: See [The default value of an optional parameter must be constant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61956960/) for how to use non-`const` default arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you plan on using `a`, `b`, and `c` later, adding variables for them is not very useful, especially when they're constants.  You therefore could just use

```dart
super(l: [3, 5, -1], x: x, key: key)
```

directly, or if you really want to label the values, you could add named constants or `static` variables.

More generally, if you want variables to store intermediate computations, then you probably would be better off using a `factory` constructor (or `static` method) to create instances of your class:

```dart
class A extends P {
  A._({required List<int> l, required int x, required Key? key})
    : super(l: l, x: x, key: key);

  factory A({required int x, Key? key}) {
    var a = 3;
    var b = 5;
    var c = -1;
    return A._(l: [3, 5, -1], x: x, key: key);
  }
}
```

although note that doing that would make your class harder to derive from if you to use it as a base class later.

Comment: `factory` seems the only working way. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```dart
class A extends P {
  A({
    required int x,
    Key? key,
    int a = -1,
    int b = 5,
    int c = -1,
  }) : super(l: [a, b, c], x: x, key: key);
}
```

or try

```dart
class A extends P {
  A({
    required int x,
    Key? key,
    final int? a,
    final int? b,
    final int? c,
  }) : super(l: [a ?? 3, b ?? 5, c ?? -1], x: x, key: key);
}
```

Named constructor parameters are optional. More about [using-constructors](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#using-constructors)

Comment: I already tried that but for some strange reason it does not work. I have oversimplified my example I guess.

Comment: Can you try nullable way

Comment: the problem is that the nullable way won't make reusable the same parameters. Please look at my update, I have added a `l2`