# The default value of an optional parameter must be constant flutter with class constructor

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]For dynamic routes, I want to set the route for the detailed page in the class in the constructor. But I'm getting an error. What am I doing wrong?

```
class RoutesF {
      String varGames = '';
      static String profile = '/profile';
      static String singn = '/signin';
      static String gamesRoute = '/games';
      final String gameDetailRoute = '/games/';
    
      RoutesF({
        required this.varGames,
        this.gameDetailRoute = this.gameDetailRoute + this.varGames,
      });
    }
```

Comment: You can only use a constant as a default parameter value. You should be able to set it in the [initializer list](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#initializer-list) instead.

Comment: The error message explains what's wrong: default values for optional parameters must be compile-time constants. `this.gameDetailRoute + this.varGames` is not constant; it depends on the runtime value of `varGames`. (`gameDetailRoute` isn't constant either, although it could be declared to be one.)  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961300/ for a typical workaround if you want non-constant default values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing things in very inefficient way. If your values are const then why you are declaring them as casual fields. Look this sample. This code does what you wanted:

```
void main() {
  var route = RoutesF("someGame");
  print(route.gameDetailRoute);
}

class RoutesF {
  late final String varGames;
  static const String profile = '/profile';
  static const String singn = '/signin';
  static const String gamesRoute = '/games';
  late final String gameDetailRoute;

  RoutesF(this.varGames) {
    gameDetailRoute = "${RoutesF.gamesRoute}/$varGames";
  }
}
```

By just **EXECUTING** this. You can test that everything is working.

***Somehow, I would like to do this task by writing that:***

```
void main() {
  print(RoutesF.gameDetailRoute("someGame"));
}

class RoutesF {
  static const String profile = '/profile';
  static const String singn = '/signin';
  static const String gamesRoute = '/games';
  static String gameDetailRoute(String varGames)=>"$gamesRoute/$varGames";
}
```

I think it is much easier to maintain and easy to understand.