# The default value of an optional parameter must be constant. How can i solve?

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'image_editor_for_carousel.dart';

class Product {


final String? image;
final String? productName;
final String? productDescription;
final List<Widget> productImageSliderListForDetailedPage;


 final static List<Widget> imageSlidersDataForProductX = const [
  AssetImage('assets/magaza_dıs.jpg'),
  AssetImage('assets/2.jpg'),
  AssetImage('assets/3.jpg'),
  AssetImage('assets/4.jpg'),
]
    .map((item) => ImageEditorForCarousel(item: item,))
    .toList();

const Product({this.image,this.productDescription,this.productName,
this.productImageSliderListForDetailedPage = imageSlidersDataForProductX});


}
```

i want to set a default `List<Widget>` to `productImageSliderListForDetailedPage` but i keep getting The default value of an optional parameter must be constant error.I tried adding const , new but it didnt work how can i fix it?

Comment: `imageSlidersDataForProductX` would need to be declared `const`, but that's not possible since it's the result of calling `.map(...).toList()`.  Therefore `imageSlidersDataForProductX` cannot be `const`.  [You instead can use a sentinel value (e.g. `null`) as a default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961300/): `Product({..., List<Widget>? productImageSliderListForDetailedPage}) : productImageSliderListForDetailedPage = productImageSliderListForDetailedPage ?? imageSlidersDataForProductX;`.