# Initializing a Class used in the Constructor of another Class

Tags: dart, constructor, initialization

I'm using one class inside of another and having a hard time with initialization. This code won't compile because it says "The default value of an optional parameter must be constant" and `MyClass(x:0)` is not a constant.

```
class UpperClass {
  int a;
  MyClass b; 
  UpperClass({this.a = 0, this.b = MyClass(x:0)});
  } 

class MyClass {
  int x;
  MyClass({required this.x});
}
```

Changing the constructor to this eliminates compiler errors:

```
UpperClass({a, b}) : this.a = a, this.b = b;
```

But the documentation says the preferred, equivalent is:

```
UpperClass({this.a, this.b});
```

but here the compiler complains that a and b are null.

I'd like to understand what's really going on here. Is it ok to use the constructor that compiles? Is there a better practice?

Comment: The complaint about `null` is because you made the parameter *optional* without having a default value, so the default value is implicitly `null`.  Either make them nullable or mark them `required` instead (`UpperClass({required this.a, required this.b});`).  Read https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety.  To work around the need for a `const` default value, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61961300/.

Comment: `MyClass(x:0)` is neither marked const, nor does MyClass have a const constructor.  Can't be the default value without being const.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the value you want as default, `MyClass(x: 0)`, is not a constant.

You can fix this in one of two ways.

The first is  to make it constant, which means making the `MyClass` constructor `const`, which again requires all instance variable of `MyClass` to be final. Then do `, this.b = const MyClass(x: 0)`, at it will be allowed.

If that's too restrictive on `MyClass`, if it really cannot be a class with a `const` constructor, you cannot use a default value to initialize it.
Then you should make the parameter *nullable*, because an optional parameter must be nullable or have a default value (aka., it must have a default value, and if you don't write one, the default value will be `null`, which must then be a valid value).

That means changing the `UpperClass` constructor to:

```dart
  UpperClass({this.a = 0, MyClass? b}) : b = b ?? MyClass(x:0);
```

If you do want to use the same instance of `MyClass` every time, even if it isn't `const`, you can create a default instance:

```dart
  UpperClass({this.a = 0, MyClass? b}) : b = b ?? _defaultB;
  static final MyClass _defaultB = MyClass(x:0);
```

Comment: This is helpful, thanks! I'm still unclear why `UpperClass({a, b}) : this.a = a, this.b = b;` works and why it gives a different result than `UpperClass({this.a, this.b});`.

Comment: @Rosten `UpperClass({a, b})` is shorthand for `UpperClass({dynamic a, dynamic b})` which disables type-checking for `a` and `b` and allows `a` and `b` to be *anything* (even `null`) at compile-time.